# Bypass wifi direct popup when connecting to devices

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I want to connect two devices through wifi direct. And I don't want any user acceptance during the connection.

Suppose I have two devices A and B, A device starts the wifi direct connection process and selects the device B for connection. After selecting B device, it should automatically connects to device B.

Or is there any way in which I can enter the pin in the popup through code automatically in device B.